# Grails: ReplaceAll only in the List-Page

Tags: grails, replace, tags

In my Grails Application, I have a dataset called "Options". There is one attribute called "description" and it is mostly something like that:

`<td><p...><span..>test</span><span...> othertest</span></p></td>`

What i want is that the description is saved in the database like above. But in the List-Page of my Grails Application in the Browser, I dont want to see the HTML-tags, so see only the text.

Like that:
`test othertest`

In the Edit-Page e.g. its ok to see the whole description.

Where do i have to insert something like that:

`description = description.replaceAll(Pattern.compile(/<.*?>/, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL), '')`

I think i have to modify the list-function in the OptionsController.groovy. In the moment its like that:

`def list = {
        params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 50, 100)
        [optionsInstanceList: Options.list(params), optionsInstanceTotal: Options.count()]
    }`

Comment: use this  description.replaceAll("<(.|\n)*?>", '')

Comment: The regex isnt the problem. It works to modify the description. But I dont want to modify it in the database. I only want that the description is without the HTML-Tags in the List-Page of my Grails Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
I just had to change the following in my list.gsp:

Before:
`<td>${fieldValue(bean: optionsInstance, field: "description")}</td>`

After: 
`<td>${optionsInstance.description}</td>`

or: 
`<td>${optionsInstance.description.replaceAll("<(.|\n)*?>", '')}</td>`